# function wait to execute

Tags: matlab, events, delay

In Matlab functions can be started at events,but occasionally, like with the resize function, the events are called in rapid order and the function is called many times in succession, which can cause weird behavior and lag. Is there a way to have it listen for the event but only execute on the last event in a time range, e.g. .5 second?

I tried using a persistent variable that each one would update and it would only run if the variable still equaled what they set it to after .5 seconds, but this didn't work. Are there any clean ways to do this in Matlab or any language that I can steal ideas from?

edit:
For example here is an implementation of the persistent variable method that I tried:

```
function practice
a = uipanel('ResizeFcn',@Delay,'Units','Normalized');
uicontrol(a)
end

function Delay(s,cb)
persistent a
if isempty(a)
    a = 0;
end
a = a+1;
b = a;
pause(.1);
if b~=a
    %disp(a-b)
else
    %do work here
end
end
```

This method doesn't seem to work all the time, but that might just be because of the use of the magic number in pause(). It is also very unclear as to what it does without deep reading.

Comment: Use a persistent variable to store the last time the function was called (use `now`). When entering the function, compare that variable with current time. If difference exceeds 5 seconds, update that persistent variable and proceed with the function; else return immediately

Comment: What about first checking `mislocked` and returning if it's true, else setting [`mlock`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mlock.html), running your code and then setting `munlock` at the end? I've never tried that though so I'm sure if it works that way or not

Comment: @LuisMendo That would cause it to run only the first time it's called, not the last. Then I could only step by a single pixel every 5 seconds.

Comment: @Dan mlock I think would cause the same, only run the first function call, behavior. I'll need to look into it more.

Comment: @Hovestar If I understand correctly, what you want would require looking into the future?

Comment: @LuisMendo I tried to word it away from that, but I can simulate doing that (perhaps) by delaying the function to see if it's been called again after it was called and if not then it would run. I just need a clear way of doing that.

Comment: @Hovestar Maybe an example with specific event times would be useful, indicating when the function should be run and when not (and with what input parameters: current or earlier?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "weird behavior and lag" you see is almost always a result of callbacks interrupting each other's execution, and repeated unnecessary executions of the same callbacks piling up.

To avoid this, you can typically set the `Interruptible` property of the control/component to `'off'` instead of the default `'on'`, and set the `BusyAction` property to `'cancel'` instead of the default `'queue'`.

That won't solve all such issues (for example, you might have a callback that needs to respond to a live data feed that is just running too fast to keep up with), but for many situations it's the right approach. In particular for the situation of a `ResizeFcn` callback, it will mean that the callback will only be called if it's not already running, and so stops any piling up of callbacks, and any effects of the same function running twice at once.

Comment: Thank you, but wouldn't that end up only calling the first iteration of the function, while the last one would have the most pertinent data?

Comment: Not quite. Let's say a callback gets called. Then it gets called again. If the first execution is still running, the second call gets dropped - otherwise it runs. This is very often the behaviour you need when handling resize events - so that if a resize happens during a resize (perhaps the user is wiggling the window around randomly), you might as well just process one of them properly, drop any other pending ones, then process the next one once you're ready.